# Spotify - searching for silences in a track

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I have been searching everywhere but haven't found any documentation about the `analysis_url` `audio feature` on `Spotify API`, in order to deepen my understanding on the subject.

As far as I'm concerned, it learns the audio by `segments`, `bars`, `beats`, `sample rates`, `fade ins and outs`, `keys`, `timbre`, `mode`, `time_signature`, `tempo`etc

what I have so far is:

```
def analysis_url(track_ids):

    names = []
    tids = []

    for id_ in track_ids:
        track_id = sp.track(id_)['uri']
        tids.append(track_id)
        track_name = sp.track(id_)['name']
        names.append(track_name)

    features = sp.audio_features(tids)

    urls = [x['analysis_url'] for x in features if x]

    for url in urls:
        analysis = sp._get(url)
```

What I would like to do is find **silences** in a track, such as a 'drop' in electronic music.

how can I do that using the `analysis_url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysis comes from a company called EchoNest, which was bought by Spotify some time ago. You can find the documentation for the analysis [here](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/_static/AnalyzeDocumentation.pdf).

Segments include a loudness_max value which indicates the relatively loudness of that specific section of music (in db). Normalize those values over the song and look for segments that have a low relative loudness:

```
def normalize_loudness(filename):
    d = json.load(open(filename, 'r'))
    x = [_['start'] for _ in d['segments']]
    l = [_['loudness_max'] for _ in d['segments']]
    min_l = min(l)
    max_l = max(l)
    norm_l = [(_ - min_l)/(max_l - min_l) for _ in l]
    return (x, norm_l)
```

Using this on the song "Miss Jackson" by Panic! At The Disco, we can plot the normalized loudness values:

```
import json
from matplotlib import pyplot as pp

x, norm_l = normalize_loudness('msJackson.json')
pp.plot(x, norm_l, 'o')
pp.show()
exit()
```

Yielding:

[image: Miss Jackson]

With that you can easily find the low spots in the music:

```
print([x[i] for i in range(len(x)) if norm_l[i] < .1])
[0.0, 165.86036]
```