# Python - reduce complexity using sets

Tags: python, list, set, time-complexity, spotify

I am using `url_analysis` tools from `spotify` `API` (wrapper `spotipy`, with `sp.`) to process tracks, using the following code:

```
def loudness_drops(track_ids):

names = set()
tids = set()
tracks_with_drop_name = set()
tracks_with_drop_id = set()

for id_ in track_ids:
    track_id = sp.track(id_)['uri']
    tids.add(track_id)
    track_name = sp.track(id_)['name']
    names.add(track_name)
    #get audio features
    features = sp.audio_features(tids)
    #and then audio analysis id
    urls = {x['analysis_url'] for x in features if x}
    print len(urls)
    #fetch analysis data
    for url in urls:
        # print len(urls)
        analysis = sp._get(url)
        #extract loudness sections from analysis
        x = [_['start'] for _ in analysis['segments']]
        print len(x)
        l = [_['loudness_max'] for _ in analysis['segments']]
        print len(l)
        #get max and min values
        min_l = min(l)
        max_l = max(l)
        #normalize stream
        norm_l = [(_ - min_l)/(max_l - min_l) for _ in l]
        #define silence as a value below 0.1
        silence = [l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if norm_l[i] < .1]
    #more than one silence means one of them happens in the middle of the track
    if len(silence) > 1:
        tracks_with_drop_name.add(track_name)
        tracks_with_drop_id.add(track_id)
return tracks_with_drop_id
```

The code works, but if the number of songs I `search` is set to, say, `limit=20`, the time it takes to process all the `audio segments` `x`and `l` makes the process too expensive, e,g:

`time.time()` prints `452.175742149`

**QUESTION**:

how can I drastically reduce complexity here?

I've tried to use `sets` instead of `lists`, but working with `set` `objects` prohibts `indexing`.

EDIT: 10 `urls`:

```
[u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/5H40slc7OnTLMbXV6E780Z', u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/72G49GsqYeWV6QVAqp4vl0', u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/6jvFK4v3oLMPfm6g030H0g', u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/351LyEn9dxRxgkl28GwQtl', u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/4cRnjBH13wSYMOfOF17Ddn', u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/2To3PTOTGJUtRsK3nQemP4', u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/4xPRxqV9qCVeKLQ31NxhYz', u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/1G1MtHxrVngvGWSQ7Fj4Oj', u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/3du9aoP5vPGW1h70mIoicK', u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/6VIIBKYJAKMBNQreG33lBF']
```

Comment: `_` is a terrible name. Why would you use that?

Comment: is that relevant to the issue?

Comment: Can you save a set of tuples of the form `(l,norml)` ? Or better yet, a `dict` of the form `{l:norm}`

Comment: Have you run a profiler?

Comment: @data_garden You come here and ask us to help you with your work. It's in your interest to make it easy for people to read your code.

Comment: I think this would benefit from being made more generic. Several things you're referring to seem only applicable to `spotify` and restrict people helping.

Comment: @JETM no, how could I do that?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, the snippet is not mine, I'm only using it in the context of something else.

Comment: How long does it take for that 452 seconds example if you remove all code after `analysis = sp._get(url)`, i.e., if you only do **that**?

Comment: How many segments do you have? Honestly, it's hard to say if the bottleneck is `list` vs `set`. Indeed. Given 20 songs, I would guess that isn't your issue. You should run a profiler, as @JETM suggested. In other words, your issue isn't likely to be *asymptotic time complexity*, rather, you are in the weeds of constant factors.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't know how to do that.... I have printed `x`and `l`, and the number of segments is **HUGE**. thats where is stucks.

Comment: @StefanPochmann read my mind. I think the issue might be related to the `get` because if you're only getting 20 values back then the list comprehensions should be done super quick. If the bottleneck is the `get` then you could try using `requests` library, open a `Session` and try get the response into something that `sp` can understand.

Comment: @data_garden Then **don't** print `x` and `l` but print `len(l)` and tell us that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a search that will take this long? I'm looking at the API docs and it seems pretty compact; enough so that we can replicate without tonnes of code.

Comment: @StefanPochmann `len` 2073
2073
2501
2501
2073
2073
2098
2098
2501
2501
2073
2073
2098
2098
2501
2501
2008
2008
2073
2073
2098
2098
2071
2071
2501
2501
2008
2008
2073
2073
2071
2071
3731
3731
2073
2073
2501
2501
2098
2098
2008
2008
1707
1707
2071
2071
3731
3731
2073
2073
2501
2501
2098
2098
2008
2008
1707
1707
2177
2177
2073
2073
3731
3731
2071
2071
2501
2501
2098
2098
2008
2008
2608
2608`
and counting

Comment: Please see my previous comment. And also, how many URLs are you searching?

Comment: @data_garden Huh? Those are way more than 20 values, and they're not really huge. Also, what about my earlier question about testing just that `sp._get(url)` line?

Comment: @roganjosh `len(url)` gives me 64.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think it might be because the whole thing is encased in `for url in urls:` and there could be any number of lookups there.

Comment: @data_garden wrong person, there's a few of us looking at this :) Please can you just give a repeatable example so that we can test ourselves? If `urls` is a gigantic list, give a selection of 10 and tell us how long your real list is. Then we can gauge roughly how long our changes take to execute overall.

Comment: @roganjosh I deeply appreciate it! would you like me to edit it and display the whole code here?

Comment: @data_garden please. The API looks compact so it shouldn't be hard to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with 10 URLs so we can actually see the bottleneck ourselves.

Comment: @roganjosh Judging by their [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39323185/1672429) that they "forgot" to tell us about as well as the answer there (where the code is from) and [this documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-audio-features/) I get the feeling that it's one URL per song.

Comment: @roganjosh there you go, help yourself, thank you

Comment: This isn't an MCVE because I asked twice for 10 URLs and something that we can copy/paste. You don't show how you call these functions. @StefanPochmann well at least we know where all the `_` comes from in the code I guess.

Comment: @roganjosh I dont see what you mean. this is what you need to run it...sorry I'm a noob

Comment: @data_garden so if I copy/paste this into my code editor and run it, I'll suddenly start searching spotify for songs? I suspect what will happen is that it will do nothing at all. I'm asking for some example `track_ids` that get passed to `loudness_drops`. At this point I'm thinking it's going to be near impossible to help you out on this.

Comment: @roganjosh ah ok, 1 sec

Comment: @data_garden That's what an MCVE is. I should be able to copy/paste and just click run to see the issue myself.

Comment: @roganjosh there you go again. refere to edit. I hope this helps.  thank you for you kindness and patiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I see, not knowing much about spotify:

```
for id_ in track_ids:
    # this runs N times, where N = len(track_ids)
    ...
    tids.add(track_id)  # tids contains all track_ids processed until now
    # in the end: len(tids) == N
    ...
    features = sp.audio_features(tids)
    # features contains features of all tracks processed until now
    # in the end, I guess: len(features) == N * num_features_per_track

    urls = {x['analysis_url'] for x in features if x}
    # very probably: len(urls) == len(features)

    for url in urls:
        # for the first track, this processes features of the first track only
        # for the seconds track, this processes features of 1st and 2nd
        # etc.
        # in the end, this loop repeats N * N * num_features_per_track times
```

You should not any url twice. And you do, because you keep all tracks in `tids` and then for each track you process everything in `tids`, which turns the complexity of this into O(n<sup>2</sup>).

In general, always look for loops inside loops when trying to reduce complexity.

I believe in this case this should work, if `audio_features` expects a set of ids:

```
# replace this: features = sp.audio_features(tids)
# with:
features = sp.audio_features({track_id})
```

Comment: great. now it times `96.9759500027`, or `4.66 X faster`.

Comment: @data_garden The next thing is to try running the profiler, as others suggested. See the example in [`profile.Profile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#profile.Profile).